# A command line that works in a prompt and not in a script

Tags: bash, shell, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

Here is the exact command

```
bcftools norm -f /path/hg19/ucsc.hg19.fasta -c s ./user1.vcf -o ../fixed/user2.vcf
```

When I run it in the shell directly it works fine.
When i put it into a bash script it fails

The error message comes from bcftools itself

> [main] Unrecognized command.

Script is encoded in ascii:

```
#!/bin/bash
bcftools norm -f /path/hg19/ucsc.hg19.fasta -c s ./user1.vcf -o ../fixed/user2.vcf
```

So bcftools accept argument when received directly from prompt but not within the script. It is like spaces from prompt and from script are not interpreted the same way

Comment: Likely to be an issue with path.. Is the paths in your script relative to the location of the script?

Comment: @sjsam Thx for answering. No it is not. Anyway, I execute the script and the command line from the same directory.

Comment: Most likely an environment difference -- is `$BASH_ENV` set?  If so, does that file set any environment variables that affect the running of `bcftools`?  You might try using `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash --posix`

Comment: Can you run *any* `bcftools` command, or is `norm` the only one that causes a problem? Did you type the command in the script, or did you copy and paste it from somewhere?

Comment: What's the output of `type -all bcftools`, at the prompt, and in the script?

Comment: Is that the full error message?  Usually after 'Unrecognised command' it gives which command is unrecognised.  Looking at the C source:  `fprintf(stderr, "[E::%s] unrecognized command '%s'\n", __func__, argv[1]);`  So there should be something inside single quotes.  Do you have more than one version of `bcftools` installed?

Comment: A useful tool when debugging is to change your hashbang to `#!/bin/bash -x`, which will print out every command as it's run.

Comment: Thanks to everyone I was not expecting so much answers. I got it thanks to @cdarke. I was using an alias to bcftools that was refering a recent version while there were an old version used by everyone else in /usr/bin. I added mine in the beginning of $PATH for my user. If you want to rephrase it cdarke, I will make it the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the full error message? Usually after 'Unrecognised command' it gives which command is unrecognised. Looking at the C source:

```
fprintf(stderr, "[E::%s] unrecognized command '%s'\n", __func__, argv[1]);
```

So there should be something inside single quotes - the `argv[1]` in the code.

The most common reason in web chatter for this message is that certain commands are not available in early versions of `bcftools`.  So, do you have more than one version of `bcftools` installed?

Comment (above) by the OP confirms that an alias referred to an earlier version.